# Correct way to package ambient module in typescript for npm

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript1.8

Assuming I have wrote a npm package called **get-subject** with source `src/index.ts` like this:

```
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rx';

export default function getSubject() {
  return new ReplaySubject(1);
}
```

I have package.json:

```
"main": "lib/index.js",
"typings": "lib/index.d.ts",
```

And tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "outDir": "lib"
    },
    "files": [
      "src/index.ts",
      "node_modules/rx/ts/rx.all.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Now I run `tsc -d` and it generates files in `lib/`:

```
lib/index.js
lib/index.d.ts
```

And `lib/index.d.ts` looks like

```
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rx';
export default function getSubject(): ReplaySubject<{}>;
```

### Time to use npm package "get-subject" as a dependency

Do normal `npm i`. Wrote some code using get-subject package:

```
import getSubject from 'ts-npm-package';

getSubject()
```

But when I run `tsc`, it tells me:

```
node_modules/get-subject/lib/index.d.ts(1,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rx'.
```

If I include `node_modules/rx/ts/rx.all.d.ts` (I use npm@3 so the Rx dependency is not nested under `get-subject`) in `files` property in tsconfig.json. `tsc` will work. **But this is the ideal solution? Could I provide a way so that package user won't have to figure out what's missing by themselves?**

Comment: Does it work if you add rx.all.d.ts to the lib folder?

Comment: @rgvassar you mean just copy rx.all.d.ts to lib/ ? No just tried. Not working.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. In my opinion you shouldn't have to do that anyway. I think if you have "moduleResolution": "node", it should look in the node_modules folder for any dependency definition files too. I'd post it as an issue on the [TypeScript GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) and see what the devs say.

Comment: @rgvassar Good idea. I think the problem is that the type definition of Rx is not declared in its package.json. It's stored under `ts/` directory which is not really a standard.

Comment: I didn't realize that would matter. Good info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But this is the ideal solution?

Yes. Until rx.js ships with its `.d.ts` files being *right* next to its `.js` files.

Comment: Sad that ts doesn't support such use case, since module without a standard type definition is so common.