# What is the correct way for a TypeScript NPM package to depend on an ambient module?

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript package that subclasses EventEmitter from the eventemitter3 JavaScript package. Because EE3 isn't written in TypeScript, I have its module definition installed as an ambient dependency via Typings.

I just spent the past hour reading up on TS inheritance and classes because I tried to consume my package and kept getting errors that `on` was missing on a subclass of an EventEmitter. Eventually I realized that my consuming project also needed to run `typings install --ambient eventemitter3` so that it had the superclass definitions

Is there any way to hide this implementation detail from consuming packages? I.e. either dump the eventemitter3 declarations into my own package's lib/index.d.ts automatically, or somehow install this ambient dependency whenever someone consumes my package?

I don't think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852764/correct-way-to-package-ambient-module-in-typescript-for-npm) because I think what the author is doing there is working with an NPM package that already defines its own declarations. In my case, I'm building a TypeScript-based NPM package that provides its own declaration, but that pulls in ambient declarations from Typings.

If it helps, the project I'm building is [here](https://github.com/ndarilek/node-janus). New to TypeScript and this is the first time I've soldiered through all the non-error compiler errors, so go easy on my missing/`any` types. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to hide this implementation detail from consuming packages

No. Its the same as `node.d.ts`. This is stuff that the user needs to get and you need to mention that they need to get.